How to authenticate a user to Auth0 from an IntelliJ plugin?
I am working on an IntelliJ plugin in Kotlin and need to authenticate users via Auth0 on some custom domain auth.myservice.com.
I've seen other IntelliJ plugins that authenticate the user they open the browser, navigate to the auth URL, and then return to IntelliJ
after the authentication process for a callback, and I wonder how to do that myself.
Unfortunately, the documentation hasn't given me much direction so far.
Any direction to achieving this would be much appreciated
I tried linking to Auth0 authorize URL:
val authUrl = "https://auth.myservice.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=intellij://callback&scope=openid profile email"
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(URI(authUrl))

And opening a server with
val server = HttpServer.create(InetSocketAddress(12345), 0)
                        server.createContext("/callback") { exchange -> ... }

server.start()

But this didn't work, I believed it listened to localhost but I don't think this is possible in production (what will be the redirect_uri?).
